# Optimize plan with conditional UNION

Tags: sql-server, parameters, devexpress, union, sql-execution-plan

I am making a report that needs cascading parameters. It is left to the user to choose whether or not to use cascading for the parameters.

To allow cascading, we need to pass the Date to filter it at runtime (runtime of the report tool we are using).

I made this query that selects data depending of a cascading parameter:

```
SELECT
    TableA.Value,
    NULL AS Date
FROM Devises
WHERE @cascading = 0

UNION

SELECT DISTINCT
    TableA.Value,
    TableE.Date

FROM TableA
INNER JOIN TableB
    ON TableA.Id = TableB.TableAId
INNER JOIN TableC
    ON TableB.Id = TableC.TableBId
INNER JOIN TableD
    ON TableC.Id = TableD.TableCId
INNER JOIN TableE
    ON TableD.Id = TableE.TableDId
WHERE @cascading = 1;
```

The DISTINCT is to prevent the report tool to work for nothing, since it will sort and eliminate duplicates. (But it might be better to let the tool eliminate duplicates to have a better SQL)

The upper part of UNION is faster then the lower part. It is ok and obvious, but the problem is while running the entire query. The performance is bad for both of them. Apparently, SQL is not optimizing the plan correctly; if @cascading <> '1', don't do the lower part of the UNION at all!

I tried using an IF ELSE statement:

```
IF @cascading = '0'
-- upper part
ELSE
-- lower part
```

It worked perfectly, but our report tool, DevExpress, does not allow anything but SELECT statements.

I tried using `OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR (@cascading = '0'))`, but it did apparently nothing significant.

Here is a [link to fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/QdsulMMK) and with template data

Do you have any idea or suggestions to tell SQL how to use this query efficiently? Or do you have anything that could be useful?

Comment: What happens with UNION ALL instead of UNION? If only one half of the result can be returned then the additional DISTINCT applied by default seems unnecessary (and could force additional logic for the optimizer). Also, does your report tool not support _stored procedures_? I might suggest investigating a better report tool.

Comment: I tried using UNION ALL instead of UNION like you suggested and the plan is still not better.

Comment: Did you also try removing the DISTINCT? Is it necessary or are you masking a bad join or something that should be an EXISTS?

Comment: Without a DISTINCT wow performance is back! Like expected, the query is fast on the first part and slower on the second like expected! I thought adding a DISTINCT would reduce high redundancy and be more efficient, but I was wrong. Thank you for your help!

Comment: The cost of sorting in order to remove duplicates (that might not even exist!) is often much more expensive than the cost of returning extra rows.

Comment: Think about donating t-shirts to charity. Is it more work for you to just donate all of your t-shirts in one pass, or to only donate the ones that are discolored, misshapen, or no longer fit? There's a point where _all_ is more work than _picking one by one_, especially if _all_ won't fit in your car in one trip, and it's a bad analogy because you probably do want to keep some, but I would argue that most of the time it's more work to sort.

Comment: ^ this is how the database engine thinks. It's far easier for the engine just to return all the matching rows than to think about each row and whether that row has been seen before. It can only do that by sorting.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it needs to be a UNION. If you need DISTINCT in only one of the queries, keep it localized and use UNION ALL, which doesn't introduce additional and unnecessary sort operators that have to manage both sides of the union.

I also don't think the second query needs a DISTINCT. Since you only care about rows from two of the tables, maybe:

```
SELECT
    TableA.Value,
    NULL AS Date
FROM dbo.Devises
WHERE @cascading = 0

UNION ALL

SELECT 
    a.Value,
    e.Date    
FROM dbo.TableA AS a
INNER JOIN dbo.TableE AS e
ON EXISTS
(
   SELECT 1 FROM TableB AS b
     INNER JOIN dbo.TableC AS c
     ON c.TableBId = b.Id
     INNER JOIN dbo.TableD AS d
     ON d.TableCId = c.Id
     WHERE d.Id = e.TableDId
     AND b.TableAId = a.Id
)
WHERE @cascading = 1;
```

(But, [sample data and desired results](https://sqlblog.org/fiddle), including whatever edge cases made you include DISTINCT in the first place, would go a lot further to be sure.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Does the subquery missing a INNER JOIN before the first ON?

Comment: @ZacharyDionne Oh, yes. This is why a fiddle is better to work from. :-)

Comment: Yes that is true, i did not know about fiddle, that is cool.